# How can I return data from thread to aspx page from a class library using Callback method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, multithreading

I have an asp.net webpage that uses Angularjs to render the data. My requirement is to render data on page if the data is returned from DB within 5 seconds. Fetching of data from DB needs to be done in separate thread so that it does not hold main thread after 5 seconds. If time taken to fetch data from DB is greater than 5 seconds, the page will be redirected to another page and thread will save fetched data into DB. How can I do this?
I am using Ajax call to fetch data from DB. I have created a WebMethod on aspx code behind file that will call a method in class library to fetch the data. Following is the snippet of my Ajax call and WebMethod
[Ajax call and WebMethod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4JNI.jpg)

In the class library, I have created a method that will create a BackgroundWorker object and Invoke the method in background to fetch data from DB. I have created global variables that will be updated in bg_DoWork when the data is fetched from DB. [Class library methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iveMK.png)

But the updated value is not received in the main thread and the main thread keeps waiting for the data. I have tried creating a thread as well but could not return data from the thread to the page.

Can anyone tell, what I am doing wrong and how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: I am new here and could not attach images to the actual question. Images are there as links. Please help.

Comment: Don't include images of code! Post them in the question.

Comment: You don't really need background worker there, and your global variables will be erased after the request is complete. You already have a threads in ASP.NET, and you don't have to create them by yourself. Set a timer on the page, redirect user to other page, and store results in memory or other cache